# Whitelisted user cannot open opt-in link

Tags: actions-on-google

I have published an alpha version of my action quite a while ago.  I'm trying to determine the bare minimum to get it visible to testers.

I have whitelisted the one email account I had created for this test.

If I add them and send them the opt in link, it opens a page with the title "null" and says something along the lines of "we can't find what you're looking for..."

If I open the same link as the owner of the action it works fine.

What do I need to do to enable white listed users to access the action on their devices?

Answer (score 0):

The link must be opened on a mobile device that has the Assistant installed. It can't be opened on the web. (The Assistant is the one that actually needs to go to the page - not a browser.)

The approach I usually use is:

- In the Assistant, make sure it is set to the account you want to use. I usually go to the "Explore" screen and click my user avatar in the upper right to set it to the right one.
- Send the link to the authorization page via email, hangouts, or some other chat.
- Open that link by clicking on it. If you're prompted for an app to use to open the link, select Google or Google Assistant.

Comment: So I switched my phone over to the account I want to test, and I click the link I emailed myself.  Im not sure howto make the assistant go to the page instead of the browser... If i paste the url into the voice assistant it tries to understand the link, not go to it...

Comment: So I had been using the built in google assistant on my Pixel 3.  I went and installed the google assistant app.  I assume this is redundant and have no idea what it actually does.  Either way, It didn't seem to make a difference.

When I open the link, however, I don't get prompted for a app to use to open the link.  The "Opening links" setting on my phone doesn't have any reference to google assistant.

Comment: The app is just a different way to access the same built-in Assistant. Is the account you're using for the Assistant the same as the one you're inviting to Alpha? How are you selecting the link?

Comment: I have several accounts setup on the phone but I have changed the active one to the one i'm trying to test (and its also the active one in the assistant)

I emailed myself the link and I'm clicking it in the gmail app (of the whitelisted user, ofc).

I've also tried pasting the url into the assistant, but it just says it doesn't understand.